# how lua_rawlen work

Tags: lua

I am tring to get table length with lua_rawlen, code like this

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);

lua_pushstring(L, "k0");
lua_pushstring(L, "v0");
lua_settable(L, -3);
lua_pushstring(L, "k1");
lua_pushstring(L, "v1");
lua_settable(L, -3);

printf("%d\n", lua_rawlen(L, -1));
```

output is 0, seems it should be 2, what's wrong with it? thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `lua_rawlen` returns the length of a *sequence* without calling the optional metamethod `__len`. It is the equivalent of Lua function `rawlen`, which is the same as the `#` operator when there is no such `__len` metamethod.

Your table is not a sequence, since you only put string keys. The keys of a sequence must be consecutive integers starting from **1**. Instead of `"k0"` and `"k1"` for keys, try with `1` and `2` respectively.

Example:

```
lua_createtable(L, 0, 0);

lua_pushstring(L, "v0");
lua_rawseti(L, -2, 1);
lua_pushstring(L, "v1");
lua_rawseti(L, -2, 2);

printf("%d\n", lua_rawlen(L, -1));
```